# When using triggerNow for Quartz job in Grails, will it run on current server in cluster

Tags: grails, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I am using Grails and Quartz Scheduler.

If I have a cluster of nodes setup, and I start a job by calling triggerNow(), is the job guaranteed to run on the current node, or can it run on any random node in the cluster?

Comment: How are you managing your nodes?

Comment: @dhamibirendra: From what perspective?  Managing for Grails?  For Quartz?

Comment: "cluster of nodes setup"..?

Comment: @dhamibirendra: Basically as recommended at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479438/grails-clustering-quartz-jobs-sample-code-and-config-desired 
I am trying to figure out how to distribute the jobs properly.