# Grails Quartz Clustering - Scheduler still running independently

Tags: tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler, load-balancing, failover

My problem is, when i run two tomcat instance in cluster mode with a scheduler that called every 10 seconds

```
println "called: " + new Date()
```

then every tomcat instance would call that print independently. If i set Quartz configuration for handling clustering, it is not supposed to be like that.

For example, when tomcat A started at 8:00:00 and tomcat B started at 8:00:05, then scheduler should be called in tomcat A at 8:00:10 and Tomcat B should **not** be called in 8:00:15. But in my case, the scheduler triggered in tomcat A at 8:00:10 and tomcat B at 8:00:15 then the next is tomcat A at 8:00:20 and tomcat B at 8:00:25 and so on. It looks like my scheduler is running independently and not in sync.

Is this the correct behavior or there are something that i miss?

Here is my config

**quartz.properties**

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479438/grails-clustering-quartz-jobs-sample-code-and-config-desired
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = HartakuClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 5000
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25

# Detect the jvm shutdown and call shutdown on the scheduler
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true

org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/latihanclust?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password =
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections = 8
```

**QuartzConfig.groovy**

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = true
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
    exposeSchedulerInRepository = false

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    }
}

environments {
    test {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = false
        }
    }
}
```

**TestingJob.groovy**

```
class TestingJob {
    static triggers = {
        simple startDelay:10000, repeatInterval: 10000l // execute job once in 10 seconds
    }

    def execute() {            
        println "called: " + new Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: Include your job class as well (you don't need to include the contents of execute()).

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, pay attention to how you configure a job. Name, Concurrent, Group, etc. https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2 I suspect if you set `def concurrent = false` and `def durable = true` on your job this will fix your issue.

Comment: Note that [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka: clustering) refers to a *data mining technique*. Not to generic server "cluster"ing. There are more appropriate tags such as [tag:load-balancing], [tag:failover] etc. Please tag more carefully. Thank you.